# Julia problem reading relatively large csv file

Tags: julia

Using Julia 1.0.0
I have a csv file with 75 columns and about 700,000 rows. Up until yesterday my code was reading it in seconds and converting to DataFrame.

```
RawDat = CSV.read("filename.csv", header=true, rows_for_type_detect=500, 
missingstring="", categorical=false, types=dictm)
```

A couple days ago I installed JLD.jl which triggered several packages to update. I had probably not updated my packages, including CSV and DataFrames, for a couple months. Since the updating, I can no longer read the same CSV file. The code hangs for more than 20 minutes and nothing is happening.

I tried using CSV.File since it seems like CSV.read was deprecated. This reads the file but I still cannot convert it to DataFrame.

```
RawDat = CSV.File("filename.csv", header=1, missingstring="", 
          categorical=false, types=dictm)
```

works but then if I try

```
RawDat1 = DataFrame(RawDat)
```

it hangs and nothing is happening. Similarly, if I try

```
RawDat = CSV.File("filename.csv", header=1, missingstring="", 
          categorical=false, types=dictm) |> DataFrame
```

the file is not read.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how I can read this csv file into a DataTable? I have a lot of downstream code that uses DataTable features to process this file.

**EDIT**

I believe I figured it out and posting in case others have a similar issue. I was able to convert the file to a DataFrame one column at a time. It was pretty quick but overall I think this should be done automatically without the need for extra lines of code. This is what worked so far:

```
datcols = Tables.columns(RawDat)
MyDF = DataFrame()
kcs = keys(datcols)
for ci in kcs
    MyDF[ci] = datcols[ci]
end
```

Comment: Can you file an issue on GitHub? Ideally you could provide a file to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user9894926, maybe you could provide a code that generates randomly (with seed=0) 700k lines with 75 cols with similar structure to your data. In this case there is a good chance that the example could be replicated. Unfortunately, Julia still is not as robust at handling CSV as R.

Comment: @user9894926, did you get the solution for this? I have a similar data of 900,000 rows and I want to read into julia